# How do I repeat background image on Flex Spark?

Tags: android, css, apache-flex

I'm making a android app. But I couldn't add a background. 
It's work:

```
<s:VGroup x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:BitmapFill source="@Embed('images/bg.png')" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:VGroup>
```

But it do not repeat.. How I do repeat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifiy `fillMode`:

```
<s:BitmapFill source="@Embed('images/bg.png')" fillMode="repeat"/>
```